# Linked list being overwritten instead of attached to another linked list

Tags: c, list, embedded

This is written in C.

I'm trying to take user input and use it to create/add to a linked list, which I point to with `struct Node *dict;` Everything is accomplished using global memory.

Creating a new linked list works fine, but when the user tries to add to the linked list, it overwrites the extant linked list.

Here's my code for adding to the list (`words` is an array of nodes to be appended to the list):

```
if (dict == NULL) { // If previous list does not exist, global dict pointer should point to node array
    dict = words;
} else {  // Else find end of current linked list and point it to the new list
    struct Node *head = dict;
    while (head->next != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = words;
}
```

When I create a list with the words "apple orange peach," for example, when I print the list, I get the output "apple orange peach." But then when I add "pear" to the list, "apple orange peach" is overwritten and I only see the output "pear," instead of "apple orange peach pear."

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>

//// GUI Stuff ////
void drawDashedLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void drawDottedLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf(".");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void drawArrowLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf(">");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void drawStarLine() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct Node {
    int length;
    char word[5];
    struct Node * next;
};
// Pointer to global linked list dictionary
struct Node *dict;

struct Node *newDict;


void printDict() {
    drawDottedLine();
    struct Node * head = dict;
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", head -> word);
        head = head -> next;
    }
    drawDottedLine();
    return;
}
void alphabetizeDict() { // Bubble sort
    //printf("%p --- %p\n", dict, dict->next);
    struct Node * head = dict;
    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    struct Node * ptr2 = NULL;

    int swapped = 1;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = 0;
        head = dict;
        while (head -> next != ptr2) {
            char * temp1 = strdup(head -> word);
            char * temp2 = strdup(head -> next -> word);

            strupr(temp1);
            strupr(temp2);
            if (strcmp(temp1, temp2) > 0) {
                char temp[5];
                strcpy(temp, head -> word);
                strcpy(head -> word, head -> next -> word);
                strcpy(head -> next -> word, temp);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            head = head -> next;
        }
        ptr2 = head;
    }
    return;
}
void createDict() {
    // To hold the string entered by the user
    char str[5000];
    // Holds 1000 words, each up to 5 characters long (4 plus a NULL char)
    char newString[1000][5];
    printf("\n");
    drawArrowLine();
    printf("Enter word(s): \n");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    int i, j, ctr;
    j = 0;
    ctr = 0; // ctr to iterate through words, j to iterate through letters
    for (i = 0; i <= (strlen(str)); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0') { // This is whitespace. add null character to terminate string. Start next word
            newString[ctr][j] = '\0';
            ctr++;
            j = 0;
        } else { // Else add letter to string
            newString[ctr][j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
            struct Node n;
            n.length = strlen(newString[i]);
            int c = 0;
            char sub[5];
            // Only use word's first four letters
            while (c < strlen(newString[i]) && c < 4) {
                sub[c] = newString[i][c];
                c++;
            }
            sub[c] = '\0';
            strcpy(n.word, sub);
            n.next = NULL;
            
            if (dict == NULL) {
                dict = &n;
            } else {
                n.next = dict;
                dict = &n;
                }
        }
    

        
    // alphabetizeDict();
    printf("Word(s) added succesfully\n");
    drawArrowLine();
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void destroyDict() {
    printf("Starting new dictionary......\n");
    while (dict != NULL) {
        struct Node * temp = dict;
        dict = dict -> next;
        temp -> next = NULL;
    }
}
void caseInsensSearch(char * searchTerm) {
    for (int i = 0; searchTerm[i]; i++) {
        searchTerm[i] = tolower(searchTerm[i]);
    }
    struct Node * head = dict;
    int index = 0;
    while (head != NULL) {
        char lowercaseWord[5];
        for (int i = 0; head -> word[i]; i++) {
            lowercaseWord[i] = tolower(head -> word[i]);
        }
        if (strcmp(lowercaseWord, searchTerm) == 0) {
            printf("Found %s at index %i\n", head -> word, index);
            drawDashedLine();
            return;
        }
        head = head -> next;
        index++;
    }
    printf("Sorry, I couldn't find %s in your dictionary.\n", searchTerm);
    drawDashedLine();
    return;
}
void caseSensSearch(char * searchTerm) {
    struct Node * head = dict;
    int index = 0;
    while (head != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(head -> word, searchTerm) == 0) {
            printf("Found %s at index %i\n", head -> word, index);
            drawDashedLine();
            return;
        }
        head = head -> next;
        index++;
    }
    printf("Sorry, I couldn't find %s in your dictionary.\n", searchTerm);
    drawDashedLine();
    return;
}

void search() {
    int isSens;
    drawDashedLine();
    printf("Enter 1 for Case sensitive\n2 for case insensitive\n");
    drawDashedLine();
    scanf("%d", & isSens);
    while (isSens < 1 || isSens > 2) {
        printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 2:\n");
        scanf("%d", & isSens);
    }
    drawDashedLine();
    printf("Enter a word to search for:\n");
    char searchTerm[5];
    scanf("%s", searchTerm);
    searchTerm[4] = '\0';
    if (isSens == 1) {
        caseSensSearch(searchTerm);
    } else {
        caseInsensSearch(searchTerm);
    }
}

int promptUser() {
    drawStarLine();
    printf("1) Search for a word\n2) Add word(s)\n3) Print dictionary\n4) Start new dictionary\n5) Exit\n");
    drawStarLine();
    printf("\nEnter a number between 1 and 5:\n");

    int choice;
    scanf("%1d", & choice);
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
        printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 5:\n");
        scanf("%d", & choice);
    }
    return choice;
}

int main() {

    for (;;) {
        int choice = promptUser();
        fflush(stdin);
        if (choice == 1) {
            search();
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            createDict();
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            printDict();
        } else if (choice == 4) {
            destroyDict();
        } else if (choice == 5) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You have to create a temporary variable to store the address of the current node.

Comment: `"words is an array of nodes to be appended to the list"`... One adds items, one at a time, to a linked list... Without seeing more code, this statement makes me suspect you're mixing arrays with LLs in a bad way...

Comment: @Fe2O3 But we can create a LS of words. The problem is the already created LS is getting overridden once it is printed. May be a problem of Dynamic Memory Allocation as well. Need to see the remaining part of code.

Comment: @SubhodipRoy Without seeing more of the code, speculation is simply speculation... `:)`

Comment: Thank you for posting.... Right off I can see that `char word[5];` won't properly contain "Apple", "Orange", or "Peach".... Would you like to revise the problem description???

Comment: Forget that part. The issue is the overwriting of the list.

Comment: `struct Node words[ctr]; // To create node for each word`... `words` is allocated on the stack and will become 'undefined' when `createDict( )` returns. Copying its address to a global variable, and then accessing that array after the function has exited leads to undefined behaviour...

Comment: @fe203 I've edited it so as not to use that array at all. I'm still having the same problem. See my edit please.

Comment: Will take a look at new version... `char * temp1 = strdup(head -> word);` In the meantime, just spotted that... `strdup( )` hides the fact that it is allocating memory from the heap. Without releasing those myriad tiny blocks, your program will "leak memory"...

Comment: Looked at new version. Still using 'stack' storage, but only a single 'node' this time instead of array of them. If you want a dynamic Linked List, you are going to have to use `malloc( )` or `calloc( )` to grow the list as you chop up the 'word string'... May be time to go to the books for that, or search SO for questions/answers about dynamic Linked Lists... (The "GUI" part should have been added AFTER the functional part was proven to work.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 I appreciate you looking over it. I was specifically asked not to use malloc, calloc, free, etc. It needs to all be done globally.

Comment: Without allocation, you don't need a linked list... Just use a global 2D array (also called an "object pool"... No need for 'nodes'; just store words into that array. Yes, such an array can still be sorted once it is populated. Very simple problem, but your 'dict' will be `char dict[1000][5];` declared globally (along with a counter of how many words it contains... Very simple problem... (Compared to 5 byte data, 8 byte pointers are expensive... Go with the SIMPLE solution. KISS!! Keep it simple, Stupid!) `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 That's how I would have solved it if I wasn't asked to do it in this particular way. I'm also not sure why this was asked of me. A global 2d array of course would have made much more sense.

I was told to "create the linked list using global memory."

Comment: You are aware, that `strdup` is not C, it's a POSIX function. And it uses `malloc` to create a copy, and you need to `free` the returned pointer later? You may create a list implementation first, using e.g. malloc/free, but replace then the allocation by a node pool implementation. And, using linked lists, you could even provide a sorted insert function `void addNode(const char* s, int (*cmpfunc)(const char* s1, const char* s2));`.

Comment: You could also create a copy of the standard `strcmp` function implementation, and let it compare case-insensitve, by comparing lowercase letters. That could then be passed to my suggestion of `addNode` as `comparefunc`. e.g. `addNode(str, strcmp);` vs `addNode(str, strcmp_lowercase);`

Comment: You could also read in using `fgetc` instead, and skip any kind of whitespace to add to input buffer. Then, on start set  `sptr` to the beginning, until WS. Instead of WS add once `\0` and add your node. Then wait until non-WS and set `sptr` to after the `\0` and scan next words, until input buffer and or nodes are exhausted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent some time diagnosing this problem for you. The problem statement is bizarre... An array of words could be sorted (even with library `qsort()`) and grow to the fill the array to the brim, but you claim this must use both a linked list and a global "object pool" that is not dynamically allocated...

Here's some code I've compiled BUT NOT TESTED...

It should be simple to follow and expand to accommodate your requirements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {   // use 'typdef'. Less typing
    char word[5]; // VERY SHORT WORDS guaranteed
    struct Node *next;
} Node_t;

Node_t dict[ 1000 ]; // global data space
int nextNode = 0;

void printDict() { // traverse LL outputting value(s)
    for( Node_t *pn = dict; pn; pn = pn->next )
        puts( pn->word );
}

void addNode( char *data ) {
    if( nextNode + 1 >= sizeof dict/sizeof dict[0] )
        return; // Fixed size cannot grow.

    Node_t *pn = &dict[ nextNode ];
    strcpy( pn->word, data ); // "apple" WON'T fit
    nextNode++;
//EDIT:
// This is not correct.
// See code block below for correction
    if( nextNode +1 >= sizeof dict/sizeof dict[0] )
        pn->next = NULL;
    else
        pn->next = &dict[ nextNode ];
}

void createDict() {
    char str[5000]; // one lo-o-o-ong input string of short words

    printf( "Enter word(s): \n" );
    fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin );

    // chop words on spaces (or tabs) and store to LL
    for( char *cp = str; ( cp = strtok( cp, " \t" ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        addNode( cp );
}

void destroyDict() { // super simple!
    memset( dict, 0, sizeof dict );
    nextNode = 0;
    // return; // Do not need those return(s) before final closing brace.
}
```

80% of any problem is the clear understanding of what the problem is to begin with.

EDIT: Realising the code must 'straddle' both array and LL, the above was not exactly correct. Below is the necessary fix to conform with a LL having a NULL next pointer at its 'tail' node.

```
void addNode( char *data ) {
    if( nextNode + 1 >= sizeof dict/sizeof dict[0] )
        return; // Fixed size cannot grow.

    strcpy( dict[ nextNode ].word, data ); // "apple" WON'T fit

    if( nextNode ) // at node 1 or greater
        dict[ nextNode - 1 ].next = &dict[ nextNode ];

    nextNode++;
}
```

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver. This works like a charm. I very much appreciate your time.

Comment: @KompSciKid Have posted EDIT revision to `addnode()` that is correct for LL paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (dict == NULL) { // If previous list does not exist, global dict pointer should point to node array
    dict = words;
} else {  // Else find end of current linked list and point it to the new list
    struct Node *head = dict;
    while (head->next != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    struct Node *ptr = NULL;
    ptr->length = strlen(word);
    strcpy(ptr->word, sub);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    head->next = ptr;
}
```

Comment: This exits the program when trying to add additional words.

Comment: you need to loop over all the words or call the method for every word. Is there an error ? which function is used for appending the linked list ?